# Persistence Error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have a class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class X{
    @Persistent
    @Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "list-ordering", value = "date desc"))
    private List<Race> list;

    @Persistent
    private Float value;
}
```

When I try to make:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
try {
    X x = pm.getObjectById(X.class, id);
    x.setValue(listObject.getValue().floatValue());
    x.getList().add(listObject);
} finally {
    pm.close();
}
```

I'm expecting that in my X object I will add a listValue and set the value of 'value'. But the result is only adding the value in the list, ignoring the setting of ghe value!

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: This could happen if `listObject.getValue().floatValue()` returned `null`. Does it?

Comment: No. It always return a value greater than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a concurrency error.

This method is called from another piece of code that changes the same object. So the changes of this call will be ignored.